# Using bash, how can I replace the domain and port of a git clone url?

Tags: bash, git, github, gitlab

Consider the environment `GITLAB_CLONE_URL`.

My program will clone it with something like this:

```
$ myapp clone ${GITLAB_CLONE_URL}
```

As a reminder, these are valids git clone URLs:

- git@github.com:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- https://github.com/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- http://github.com/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- ssh://git@git.gitlab.com:200/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
- https://git.gitlab.com/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
- https://git.gitlab.com:31000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git

My program clone, but in some case, it does not know the domain. It must include an option in case the domain is not reachable.

```
$ myapp clone ${gitUrl} --force-domain=private
```

This will clone the following URLs:

- git@private:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- https://private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- http://private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- ssh://git@private:200/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
- https://private/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
- https://private:31000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git

Note that the last entry is having an http port, I would like to also have `--force-port=32000` and this will use a forced port:

- git@private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- https://private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- http://private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
- ssh://git@private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
- https://private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
- https://private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git

How can I interpolate the domain/port nicely to produce this result using bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies:

- GNU bash v4+
- GNU sed

I don't think that the git url `git@private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git` is valid. The port number `32000` is confused with the path. So I replace the urls like `git@github.com:foo/bar.git` with `ssh://git@github.com/foo/bar.git`

script `mygit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu -o pipefail

for param in "$@"; do
    case "$param" in
        --force-domain=*)
            private_domain="${param#*=}"
            ;;
        --force-port=*)
            private_port="${param#*=}"
            ;;
        *://*|*@*/*)
            git_url="$param"
            ;;
    esac
done

declare -a sed_opts=(-e "s,^\\([a-z]\\+\\)@\\([^:]\\+\\):,ssh://\\1@\\2/,")

[[ -n "${private_domain:-}" ]] && sed_opts+=(
        -e "s,//\\(.\\+@\\)\\?[^/:]\\+,//\\1$private_domain,"
    )

[[ -n "${private_port:-}" ]] && sed_opts+=(
        -e "s,//\\(.\\+@\\)\\?\\([^:/]\\+\\)\\(:[0-9]\\+\\)\\?,//\\1\\2:${private_port},"
    )

if [[ -z "${git_url}" ]]; then
    cat <<HELP_MESSAGE
$0 [--force-domain=domain] [--force-port=port] git-repo-url
HELP_MESSAGE
    exit 1
fi

new_git_url="$(echo "$git_url" | sed "${sed_opts[@]}")"

echo "${new_git_url}"
```

Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

declare -a test_git_urls=(
    git@github.com:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    https://github.com/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    http://github.com/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    ssh://git@git.gitlab.com:200/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
    https://git.gitlab.com/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
    https://git.gitlab.com:31000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
)

declare -a private_domain_urls=(
    ssh://git@private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git # git@private:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    https://private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    http://private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    ssh://git@private:200/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
    https://private/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
    https://private:31000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
)

declare -a private_port_urls=(
    ssh://git@private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git # git@private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    https://private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    http://private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
    ssh://git@private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi.git
    https://private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
    https://private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
)

for index in {0..5}; do
    git_url="${test_git_urls[$index]}"
    echo "$index: $git_url"

    new_git_url="$(./mygit --force-domain=private "$git_url")"
    [[ "$new_git_url" = "${private_domain_urls[$index]}" ]] && echo -n OK || echo " $new_git_url" '!=' "${private_domain_urls[$index]}"

    new_git_url="$(./mygit "$git_url" --force-domain=private --force-port=32000)"
    [[ "$new_git_url" = "${private_port_urls[$index]}" ]] && echo -n OK || echo " $new_git_url" '!=' "${private_port_urls[$index]}"
    echo ""
done
```

Examples:

```
./mygit git@github.com:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git --force-domain=private --force-port=32000
```

> ```
> ssh://git@private:32000/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
> ```

```
./mygit git@github.com:lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git --force-domain=private
```

> ```
> ssh://git@private/lab/rollup-umd-documentation.git
> ```

```
./mygit --force-domain=private --force-port=32000 \
       https://github.com:31000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
```

> ```
> https://private:32000/deploy-tools/ssl-gandi-gitlab.git
> ```

Comment: fixed it. maybe my fat finger when pasting the code.

Comment: You should use them with caution. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I use shellcheck, otherwise I cannot test this script.